# How to make web service available for cross-domain access?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this API built with Nodejs-Express:

```
app.get('/api/v1/:search', function(req, res){
        var response = {}   
        res.contentType('application/json');
                // process req.params['search']
                // build and send response
                res.send(response, response.status_code);
          });
```

However, I need to make a client that will sit on another domain. How do I fix this code so it can be called through like JQuery $.ajax, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
//Middleware: Allows cross-domain requests (CORS)
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}

//App config
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret' }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: Note: In case someone is looking at this and not picking up on it, the app.use(allowCrossDomain); from the //App config section is the key component for your app.configure() portion of code... (you have to have all of the middleware code as well)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) might be helpful to you.

Although I think JQuery already started supporting cross-domain requests using hidden iframes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I like the hack, cool. However, I need to make the web service accessible from cross-domain using standard way, the API will be a public API that is why.